# How can I troubleshoot poor web service response times when the server says response times are healthy, but the CXF client seems to perform poorly?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I’m using CXF as a web services client, calling a server hosted on a different platform.

I’ve instrumented my code around the call to the CXF port and observe that 10 – 20% of the requests perform very poorly (a “good” response time is 100 – 200ms, a “bad” one is 4000 – 5000ms, and there are very few requests that fall between “good” and “bad”).

The server-side log web access log shows that all requests response times were “good” (100 – 200ms).  For those requests that the server and client both think were “good”, there is very little latency between the client measurements and the server measurements (only a few ms additional time in the CXF client than the server thinks the request took).  Bandwidth on the network segments between the two is nowhere close to saturated.  Besides that, I don’t think network latency would inject SECONDS (perhaps milliseconds).

This only occurs under very heavy load, so packet sniffing to figure out which side of the wire the problem is on would be extremely arduous (plus, I don’t have easy access to sniff the relevant network segments).

So…here’s my question….

Is there any performance logging I can enable in CXF so that I can see “inside” CXF and try to push my visibility “closer to the wire”?

Comment: Start by capturing network traffic on the server using Wireshark or tcpdump to see what's _actually_ happening on the wire.  That will tell you where to look next.

Comment: See the question: it only occurs under very heavy load, and I don't  have access to the network segments to sniff them.  Wireshark and tcpdump aren't options.

Comment: You'll have to define what you mean by "heavy load". Server side? Client side? Network? If the server thinks the requests have all been handled in 100-200ms but sometimes you see 4000ms delays at the client, then the problem is in the TCP stack or below (i.e. packet loss).  You should first eliminate the possibility that the client is having trouble keeping up. Beyond that, you cannot troubleshoot this without getting matching network traces at both the client and server.

Comment: Are you sure it's the web service and not the connected database? Have you used soapUI (instead of your own client) to send test requests and see how performance compares?

Comment: This often happens in my situations as well. When web service is flowing through layers, each layer submits a nice Response time, but overall Latency is not matching when I sum up all these. As @JimGarrison mentioned, unless you have Network logs match up with yours, it won't give any clue. Haven't found any app level logging that can capture network latency. All you could do is collect some metrics from server and have Network team convinced to help you debug the latency.